# diff changes of disk image and restore in hdd

Tags: hard-disk, diff, external-hdd

I guys, I have a `diskimage.raw` of all a hdd (`/dev/sdd`) 100gb.

I've read image with:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 diskimage.img
```

Then I've do a modifications (like add 8gb in files)

Could I restore the diskimage.raw in hdd without override all 100gb. I like insert the different data.

Like see a **`diff`**, then inserting the new information in hdd wihout overwritting

**I would like if is possible or What is the best way?**

The reason of this question is, If you have 10TB in a disk image and you modify x or y files and then need apply changes in original hdd but supposing that you can't modify the hdd as in **"disk image"**, then you should overwrite all 10TB ... this take much time !!!!

*Note: I have this problem now!!*

Answer (score 1):

> Like see a diff, then inserting the new information in hdd wihout overwritting

The HDD has a fixed capacity. You're always overwriting *something* when you write to it.

> Like see a diff, then inserting the new information in hdd wihout overwritting

In terms of visualizing the changes to a filesystem, that sounds extremely complicated and I'm not aware of any tools that do that.

To store changes and replay them on the HDD later, you can use the `device-mapper` target `snapshot`. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt. Note that it is a fairly complex thing to set up. Basically, you would create a persistent snapshot with `/dev/loop0` as the origin. After making your changes, you would then close down the snapshot and create a `snapshot-merge` target with the HDD as the origin. Technically you are supposed to use `snapshot-origin` but I'm sure I've used (non-persistent) snapshots without it.

Comment: Ok dude, I will try it, Thank you very much